# React Search Bar with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I currently have a react-redux-application that allows for CRUD operations by using React Hooks 16.8

Does anyone know if I can add a input text search bar with Hooks, or do we have to use class components?

Comment: Yes you can. Can you post some specific code so we ca help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example how to use react hooks

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";

    export function SearchForm(props) {
      const [search, setInput] = useState("");

      const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
          evt.preventDefault();
          alert(`Submitting search ${search}`)
      }
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Search Input
            <input
              type="text"
              value={search}
              onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do that, check it on https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-sunset-r7sn3?fontsize=14.

```
function SearchBar() {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    const handleChange = val => {
        setSearchInput(val);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={searchInput} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
    )
}
```